# how to select the last line of the shell output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Hi I have a shell command like this.

```
s3=$(awk 'BEGIN{ print "S3 bucket path" }
 /Executing command\(queryId/{ sub(/.*queryId=[^[:space:]]+: /,""); q=$0 }
 /s3:\/\//{ print "," $10 }' OFS=',' hive-server2.log)
```

The output of the above command like this.

```
echo $s3

2018-02-21T17:58:22,
2018-02-21T17:58:26,
2018-02-21T18:05:33,
2018-02-21T18:05:34
```

I want to select the last line only. I need the last output like this.

```
 2018-02-21T18:05:34
```

I tried like this.

```
awk -v $s3 '{print $(NF)}'
```

Not working.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `cmd | sed -n \$p`

Comment: Can you explain the above command ?

Comment: `$` selects the last line and `p` prints it. You're not much for search engines, are you?

Answer (score 7):

In general, `command | tail -n 1` prints the last line of the output from `command`. However, where `command` is of the form `awk '... { ... print something }'` you can refactor to `awk '... { ... result = something } END { print result }'` to avoid spawning a separate process just to discard the other output. (Conversely, you can replace `awk '/condition/ { print something }' | head -n 1` with `awk '/condition/ { print something; exit }'`.)

If you already have the result in a shell variable `s3` and want to print just the last line, a parameter expansion `echo "${s3##*$'\n'}"` does that. The C-style string `$'\n'` to represent a newline is a Bash extension, and the parameter expansion operator `##` to remove the longest matching prefix isn't entirely portable either, so you should make sure the shebang line says `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`

Notice also that `$s3` without quotes is an error unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value. You should basically [always use double quotes around variables except in a couple of very specific scenarios.](/q/10067266)

Your Awk command would not work for two reasons; firstly, as explained in the previous paragraph, you are setting `s3` to the first token of the variable, and the second is your Awk script (probably a syntax error). In more detail, you are basically running

```sh
awk -v s3=firstvalue secondvalue thirdvalue '{ print $(NF) }'
          ^ value    ^ script to run   ^ names of files ...
```

where you probably wanted to say

```sh
awk -v s3=$'firstvalue\nsecondvalue\nthirdvalue' '{ print $(NF) }'
```

But even with quoting, your script would set `v` to something but then tell Awk to (ignore the variable and) process standard input, which on the command line leaves it reading from your terminal. A fixed script might look like

```sh
awk 'END { print }' <<<"$s3"
```

which passes the variable as standard input to Awk, which prints the last line. The `<<<value` "here string" syntax is also a Bash extension, and not portable to POSIX `sh`.

Comment: Grabbed the left content with left_stuff=`echo $s3 | sed "s/${s3##**$'\n'}//"`

Comment: @archcutbank That looks wrong for a couple of reasons. Without the quotes, there is no way the output from `echo` can contain a newline. (As already mentioned in the third paragraph, that's a common beginner error.) The double `**` is just redundant. I'm pretty sure you can accomplish that with just a parameter expansion anyway. Not sure what you mean by "left stuff"; what you have will remove what's on the left. Are you looking for `"${s3%%$'\n'*}"` to pick out the first line? Or `"${s3%$'\n'*}"` to get everything except the last?

Comment: It just used sed to take off the last line and left you everything else (left of the last line).

Comment: The backticks disappeared because that's how you mark up `code` in comments. I mean you need `echo "$s3"` with double quotes around the string variable. And as noted in my previous comment, you don't need `sed` for this, any more than for the opposite operation. In shell scripting, you generally want to avoid calling external processes when you can.

Answer (score 4):

much simple way is

```
command | grep "your filter" | tail -n 1
```

or directly

```
command | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
echo -e "This is the first line \nThis is the second line" | awk 'END{print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach can be, processing the file from the end and exiting after first match.

```
tac file | awk '/match/{print; exit}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can do it just by adding `echo $s3 | sed '$!d'`

```
s3=$(awk 'BEGIN{ print "S3 bucket path" }/Executing command\(queryId/{ sub(/.*queryId=[^[:space:]]+: /,""); q=$0 } /s3:\/\//{ print "," $10 }' OFS=',' hive-server2.log)

echo $s3 | sed '$!d'
```

It will simply print:-

```
2018-02-21T18:05:34
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Without quotes, the `echo` will only ever produce a single line. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)